# Why can't I install multiple Debian packages at a time using apt-get install?

Tags: debian, apt-get, package-managers

i'm face a problem when trying to install multiple packages

So for example when i try this :

```
apt-get install php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json etc..
```

i get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json
```

But i have no trouble installing the packages on at a time.

Am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: The command looks correct. If you ate entering it exactly like that, it should work. The error looks like you have some wrapper in place, either a shell alias or a misbehaving program you are entering this command into (perhaps a PHP script you need to tell us about?)

Comment: No, I'm doing this on a fresh debian 7 install. Apart from apache2 and the standard packages that come with debian, nothing else is installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't run apt-get with admin rights. In order to do that make sure you use `sudo`
before you execute apt-get.

Here is the full command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get the same result when using sudo.  
`E: Unable to locate package php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json php5-mcrypt` . Do you think it's a syntax problem ?
The error message makes me think that _apt-get_ is considering the package names (for ex : **php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json php5-mcrypt** ) as a single package name, which it obviously doesn't recognize

Comment: Looks like the package isn't in the repos. Try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json`

Comment: Yup, tried that as well but It doesn't help. What's weird is that I can install the packages one at a time which means they definitely are in the repos (but you can imagine how tedious it can be). It's the 'bulk' install that doesn't work. Thank you for taking the time to reply !

Answer (score 1):

Your error message tells the story: When calling

```
apt-get install does not exist but bash does
```

The result should be:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package does
E: Unable to locate package not
E: Unable to locate package exist
E: Unable to locate package but
E: Unable to locate package does
```

You get only one line, which means that either your shell itself or any alias or function defined in the shell for `apt-get` does not send the individual package names to the real executable as individual arguments, but as one long argument containing spaces. I think this is what [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) was pointing out.

To find out what happens:

1. If you did not type this directly into a "normal" shell but into a wrapper (a web-frontend to the shell counts as such): stop doing that or look up the documentation of the wrapper
2. If you really typed this in correctly, check if an alias or a function is defined:

   - enter: `type apt-get`
   - should return: `apt-get is /usr/bin/apt-get`
   - if it returns `apt-get is a function` or `apt-get is aliased to ...`, you have your answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Based on the results, something seems to be manipulating OP's `apt` or `apt-get` commands to be non-standard...

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same with clean ubuntu install. Running

```
apt-get update
```

helped, as it pulled latest package info.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be a copy-paste / line-endings issue. **Try putting the line with the long list of packages in its own shell file and then run it**. The following seems to work reliably:

E.g.:

```
gedit installer.sh
```

Then paste the long line and save:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-pear php-imagick php-imap php-json
```

Then set the permissions and run:

```
chmod +x installer.sh
./installer.sh
```

Comment: This is good feedback in the case of sourcing a list of packages in a bash script, but I believe OP was actually typing the command manually into his shell.